# React Apollo Client not sending cookies or Headers to Apollo Server 2.0

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I have some problems with cookies to React Apollo client and Apollo Server 2.0.
My client doesn't send cookies for my server API. I already try the responses above.

The client(react-app) running at http://localhost:3000 (React-Apollo-Client)
API running at http://localhost:4000/graphql (Apollo Server 2.0, Express with Middleware)

My Client Code:

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { gql } from "apollo-boost";

const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  credentials: 'same-origin',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  onError: ({ networkError, graphQLErrors }) => {
    console.log('graphQLErrors', graphQLErrors)
    console.log('networkError', networkError)
  }
});

client.query({ query: gql`
      {
        users{id,name} //My query in GraphQL
      }
    `
  })
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

My Server:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  credentials: true, // <-- REQUIRED backend setting
};
const app = express();

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
server.applyMiddleware({ app });
```

Could Someone help me, please?

Comment: When `credentials` is set to `same-origin` cookies are only sent to the same origin, which is `http://localhost:3000` in your case. Since your backend is located at `http://localhost:4000`, which is different from your frontend, they are not sent. Changing`credentials` to `include` would solve that problem. A better solution would be to use a proxy when developing, since I assume you don't want cors enabled in production. If you are using webpack dev server you can set a proxy option.

Comment: Thanks for your help but don't work. I've set credentials to `include` and have changed my webpack to use proxy option. I've noted when my URI is in createHttpLink I get Network error, so I put it in ApolloClient. The code changed was:

`
const link = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  credentials: 'include',
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
 ...
});
`